# Powershell Script printing garbage to Text file

Tags: powershell

I have written a simple power shell script to take user argument at run time and write it to a text file. When I read this file using my JMeter webdriver API it shows some Garbage Character. I have created a new file just to make sure that it's not JMeter that is reading incorrectly. My final conclusion is that garbage is being printed to the text file by powershell script.

Here is my script.

```
while($state -ne "GA" -or $state -ne "FL")
{
"Enter state"

$state = [Console]::ReadLine()  

if($state -eq "GA" -or $state -eq "FL")
{
Clear-Content market.txt
$state>>'market.txt'
break;
}
else
{
"NO such market"
}
}
```

Comment: And what is the [mysterious garbage character](http://images.clipartof.com/small/12785-Clipart-Picture-Of-A-Garbage-Can-Mascot-Cartoon-Character-Holding-A-Blank-Sign.jpg)?

Comment: SO, when I type GA it become ÿþG A and wehen I type FL it becomes ÿþF L

Comment: If you run the script in powershell console, does it still print garbage?

Comment: It looks like the "garbage" is the UTF-16 BOM (byte order mark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Out-File` instead so you can specify that you want the data saved in ASCII encoding (instead of the default Unicode encoding):

```
$state | Out-File market.txt -Encoding ascii
```